# How to download file from web site having liferay portlet using java code

Tags: java, liferay, portlet

i'm trying to download a file from a site , this site has a life ray server 
i have been reading to much about but all describe how to configure a server not how to read from , all examples i saw has `HTTPServletRequest` which needs a request input how can i transfer a URL to a request ,from where to start at least .
in other words :i have the URL , in the webpage i select a date and a download like is generated , how can i make it down in java ????
i tried this:

```
HttpServletRequest request = PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(PortletRequest);
```

so how to link my URL to PortletRequest

Answer (score 0):

If you have the URL of the download the only thing you need is to perform a client request against that URL.

First thing you should try to be sure that the URL you have is the one that will give you the expected results is try to paste it in a new browser window and verify that the download starts.

Then, if you want to perform that download through Java you can do very easily using the [`URL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and [`URLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) ([`HttpURLConnection`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) in this case) classes:

```
String urlString = "...";   // Your URL
URL url = new URL(urlString);
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
if (conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
   InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
   // Read the data from the stream
}
```

You could also do the same using [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/).

**Note**: `PortalUtil.getHttpServletRequest(...)` is used internally by Liferay and you won't have any access to that API if you are doing a client request.

Comment: dear Alonso , i have the download link but it has this part "p_p_auth=FM7WafZf" this authentication code varies each time i access the site , that's why i need a could that can get this first then i'll build the full URL and use the above connection

Answer (score 0):

If you're writing a portlet, by design you don't get access to the `HttpServletRequest`.

What you can do is to utilize the "resource-serving" lifecycle phase of a portlet. There you get access to a `ResourceRequest` and `ResourceResponse` object. Those objects behave almost like a `HttpServletRequest/-Response` object

As you don't name the framework that you're using: `javax.portlet.GenericPortlet.serveResource()` is the method that you want to override in the pure JSR-286 API.

On the UI side, `<portlet:resourceURL/>` will provide the URL to your portlet's resource handling method.

This should provide you with enough google-food to find tutorials on how to implement different lifecycle phases - I can't judge the required level of detail you need. Note that Liferay has quite a few sample portlets that you can utilize as a source for sample code.

**Edit:** Following your comment below, let me give you some pseudo code (just typed here, never compiled/run):

on a jsp frontend, e.g. view.jsp:

```
  <a href="<portlet:resourceURL/>">Download File</a>
```

Then, in your portlet, assuming you're implementing javax.portlet.GenericPortlet in one way or another (e.g. indirectly through Liferay's MVCPortlet or any other superclass):

```
  public class MyPortlet extends GenericPortlet {
     ....
     @Override
     public void serveResource(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) {
         // implement the file streaming here,
         // use ResourceResponse the way you find illustrated 
         // in samples for HttpServletResponse
     }
```

Comment: dear olaf , thanks for the answer but i'm new to life ray and i couldn't follow you. What i was trying to ask , is how to write a code to get files from a server where the server is using lifeRay ,